# Is it possible to exclude a CSS file when depending on a grails plugin?

Tags: grails, resources, spring-security

Grails spring security UI plugin has a stylesheet called reset.css.  This overrides my own reset.css included via another plugin.  Is there a way to my explicitly exclude the CSS file when importing spring security core?

Answer (score 0):

> The plugin defines its CSS styles in web-app/css/spring-security-ui.css and most of the jQuery plugins have corresponding CSS files. These can be overridden by overriding the springSecurityUI.gsp template and including your CSS file(s).

according to the [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-ui/docs/manual/guide/10%20Customization.html).